# What is the relationship between these three probabilities?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

$p(a|b, c)$,
$p(a|b=1, c)$,
$p(a|b=0, c)$,
$p(b=0|c)$,
$p(b=1|c)$

What are their relationships? My guess is $$p(a|b, c) = p(b=0|c)*p(a|b=0, c) + p(b=1|c)*p(a|b=1, c)$$, but I am not sure if it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct. Also your notation is ambiguous because lowercase letters seem to represent the random variable, but without the specific value $p(a)$ doesn’t make sense much. I’ll be using a more explicit notation as below. According to total probability theorem, you only have:
$$P(A=a|C=c)=\sum_{b\in \mathcal B}P(A=a|B=b,C=c)P(B=b|C=c)$$

Comment: Thank you for the corrections! I am very new to probabilities, this helped a ton!